# Delete xml elements with multiple criteria in xmlstarlet

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I am trying to write a bash script to delete xml element with multiple criteria.

For example:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <name>x</name>
  <age>15</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>A</grade>
 </b>
 <b>
  <name>x</name>
  <age>14</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>B</grade>
 </b>
 <b>
  <name>y</name>
  <age>15</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>C</grade>
 </b>
</a>
```

Here I need to delete the xml element having values name = x and age = 15

Expected output:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <name>x</name>
  <age>14</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>B</grade>
 </b>
 <b>
  <name>y</name>
  <age>15</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>C</grade>
 </b>
</a>
```

The below element should be deleted.

```
 <b>
  <name>x</name>
  <age>15</age>
  <group>maths</group>
  <grade>A</grade>
 </b>
```

Comment: please, try to rephrase your post as a question. also, let us know what you have already tried and did not work, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using xmlstarlet, try:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//b[name="x"][age="15"]' file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks much Mr. Jack. I got the expected results. One more thing I would like ask. Is there any possibility to do the same process without the help of xmlstarlet.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @NaveenSubramanian - Well, there are alternatives to xmlstarlet (I personally prefer xidel), but without using anything like that, it may be possible but very cumbersome. I haven't done it myself.